# What is the syntax for removing duplicate rows in pandas (where all of the columns match)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the syntax for removing duplicate rows of a pandas dataframe (where all of the columns match)?

I tried using:

`df.drop_duplicates()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

you have to add inplace= True